# Aligning GroupLayout in the center of screen in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, grouplayout

So if i have a GUI like this:

```
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
public class MyTest extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public MyTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("This is a sample GUI");

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);

        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 244, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 85, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MyTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

Now when i run the program, it is aligned to (0,0) position on the top-left of the screen. Is there anyway i can align this to the center of the screen or to another custom position?
This works fine if i only use a frame without using GroupLayout, like with setLocation(left,top), but with this implementation, how can i change the default positioning of this GUI?

Comment: There is no component to set layout on. I have textAreas, ScrollPanel and some Buttons inside layout, but nothing to put the layout on. I just call pack(); and setVisible(true); after defining layout and it starts showing the GUI. I took this idea from Oracle website but it does not show alignment option.
something like this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/groupExample.html

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"Is there anyway i can align it to the center of the screen or to another custom position?"* OK, now I run that code it just raises more questions.  Specifically what do you mean by 'it'?  I thought you meant the entire panel containing the group layout, but now I'm not so sure.

Comment: Also, what is the point of the label that is never added to the GUI?

Comment: @AndrewThompson, i mean i just need to center the whole GUI (with everthing in it) to the center of the scree, and for label not being added to GUI, i just follwed as is shown here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/FindProject/src/layout/Find.java

Comment: GroupLayout is not meant for humans (except if they like being tortured which is extremely rare :-) Learn and use a decent third-party manager, any of the big three will do: FormLayout, MigLayout, DesignGridLayout

Comment: What is that example supposed to be good for?  One might imagine that if trying to center a layout in a frame, one might **put components in it** for ease of testing (e.g. "is the button in the center yet?").  That code really is pointless for demonstrating anything.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, sorry for annoying you, is there any way the layout itself is in the center, it does not have any parent component. Anything inside the layout can be centered. But i want the actualy layout (the parent of everthing) to be centered. And as you already mentioend setLocationRelativeTo(null) that does not work with layout. But it works fine with JFrame. I hope you understand my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you did answer the question but it wasn't that clear to me, regarding how to use it.
Simply by calling below before pack(); was exactly what i was looking for:

```
this.setLocation(500,300); //value left, top in pixes
pack();
```

So basically what i needed to know was the exact use of `setLocation(x,y);` and that with the use of keyword `"this"`, thank you.

Comment: I don't know what question that claims to be answering, but it is surely not *"Aligning GroupLayout in the center of screen in Java Swing?"*

Comment: I have a GroupLayout layout in the constructor, and all i wanted was to center this GUI in the screen, so please tell me what sholud i have asked then?

Answer (score 4):

Put the contianer with a `GroupLayout` as the single component of a [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) with no constraint.  The entire container will be centered.

---

> i just need to center the whole GUI (with everthing in it) to the center of the scree,

That has *nothing* to do with `GroupLayout` and *everything* to do with [`setLocationRelativeTo(null)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo%28java.awt.Component%29).  But read [How to best position Swing GUIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143287/how-to-best-position-swing-guis/7143398#7143398) for an even better way to position a GUI on-screen (i.e. at a more sensible place than the center of the screen - example below).

[image]

Comment: can you show me an example. GroupLayout is not a component, then how can i add it to GridBagLayout?

Comment: Can you post an SSCCE of your current code (as I've already suggested)?  That answer is the best you'll get from me short of compilable code from you.

Comment: +1 There's a nice example and explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8276631/230513) that leverages that question's [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson, where should i apply the method setLocationRelativeTo(null). Again if i have a frame then i can call it with frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); but in this case how can i do it?

Answer (score 3):

Like I mentioned in your earlier question, before I thought you were referring to centering the frame itself - use a `GridBagLayout` with no constraint.  That will have the effect of putting the component in the center of the *parent container*.  Note that since a frame has window decorations, that means the 'parent container' itself is slightly below screen center.  If that is a problem, the only 'fix' I can think of is to use an undecorated frame.

I put 'fix' in inverted commas, because I think it is the requirement that is broken.

[image: Centered GroupLayout]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyTest extends JFrame {

    public MyTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("This is a sample GUI");
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JPanel gui = new JPanel();
        gui.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(gui);
        gui.setLayout(layout);

        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 244, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 85, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        add(gui);

        pack();
        setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MyTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: fine, i guess just the layout can not be centered in the screen. What you have shown is another component inside layout centered relative to layout. So i will have to leave it as is. Thank you