# Center JButton's in BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, alignment, border-layout

I am trying to align my buttons to CENTER, but somehow it doesnt work.

As you can see I tried it using

```
newGameBtn.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
```

but somehow its been ignored by the layout.

Here is my class (BaseView inherits from JPanel):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MenueView extends BaseView
{
    private JPanel _titlePanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel _menuItemsPanel = new JPanel();

    private JLabel _title = new JLabel("Wer wird Millionär?");
    private JButton _newGameBtn = new JButton("Neues Spiel");
    private JButton _highscoreBtn = new JButton("Highscore");
    private JButton _quitBtn = new JButton("Beenden");

    public void InitializeComponents()
    {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        _titlePanel.add(_title);

        _menuItemsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(_menuItemsPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        _menuItemsPanel.add(_newGameBtn);
        _newGameBtn.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        _menuItemsPanel.add(_highscoreBtn);
        _menuItemsPanel.add(_quitBtn);

        this.add(_titlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(_menuItemsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public MenueView(IConductor conductor)
    {
        super(conductor);
        InitializeComponents();
    }
}
```

Is it because I use a borderlayout?

Thank you for your help

[image: Alignment Issue]

Comment: Try `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

Comment: JButton.CENTER hasnt worked out. Further more BorderLayout.CENTER gives me a build error.

Comment: JButton.CENTER hasnt worked out. Further more BorderLayout.CENTER gives me a build error. == for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: Try using GridBagLayout instead of BoxLayout

Comment: and to read official Oracle tutorial - how to use BorderLayout, hint there are 5. areas ....

Comment: Thats why I used BorderLayout.CENTER for my menuitemsPanel when adding it.

Comment: Don't use JLabel.CENTER with setHorizontalAlignment the two are not compatible. The value should be left at its default value of 0.5

Comment: Related - [BorderLayout center command won't center](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8276559/2982225)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your JBUttons to a gridlayout within the Center-box of the BorderLayout, like this:

```
gridlayout.add(_newGameBtn);
gridlayout.add(_highscoreBtn);
gridlayout.add(_quitBtn);

borderlayout.add(gridlayout, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panel.setLayout(borderlayout);
```

Source:
 [How to centre the Buttons in my JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093122/how-to-centre-the-buttons-in-my-jframe)

Comment: Ist possible to add layouts to a layout?

Comment: @Jannik layouts are added to panels. I believe what is called `gridLayout` and `borderLayout` here should be in fact called ratehr `gridPanel` and `borderPanel`